# How to increment each element of 2-dimensional array by 2

Tags: c, arrays, loops, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I am asked to define an array called A which has the dimensions of 5X4. I have to initialize its elements then increase each one of them by two (x+3) in which x starts from 1.

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #define SIZE 5
  #define size 4

  int main(){
      int A[SIZE][size]={0};
      int B[SIZE][size];
      int x;
      int i;
      int j;

      for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
          for(j = 0; j < size; j++){
              for(x = 1; x < 40; x = x + 2){
                  A[i][j] = x;
                  printf("%d\n", A[i][j]);
              }                                                             
          }
      }

      return 0;
  }
```

Unfortunately, the output seems to be giving wrong and repeated values for A[i][j]

Answer (score 1):

You are iterating over 2d array here:

```
for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++){
    for(j=0;j<size;j++){

    }
}
```

Then you iterate over each element of 2d array about 20 times, change its value and printing value of here:

```
for(x=1;x<40;x=x+2){
    A[i][j]=x;
    printf("%d\n",A[i][j]);
}
```

In above code A[i][j] do not change. x will have values 1, 3, 5, 7, ... , 39.
What happens here you are assigning A[i][j]=1 and printing it. Next, you are assigning 3 to A[i][j] (note i and j didn't changed so we've changed value 1 to 3) and printing it. Another iteration will assign it to 5 etc. And this happens to each element of matrix. In the end every element will have value 39.

You should replace most inner for loop, with:

```
A[i][j] = value;
value += 2;
```

Which gives in the end

```
int value = 1;
for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++){
    for(j=0;j<size;j++){
        A[i][j] = value;
        value += 2;
        printf("%d\n",A[i][j]);
    }
}
```

You didn't clearly explained what is the initial value

Comment: The initial value for each element should be 0. However, x value for the element [0][0] should be 1 then increase  by 2 when going like [0][1]...[0][2].... so on

Comment: @utdlegend I made some edits to fit your requirements

Comment: Thank you it works now! do you have any idea about why x loop did not work?